# SQL 2008: Grouping not returning my Data correclty

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a Query that I wrote to extract data and to do a count for specific ID's , the issue that I have at the moment is that instead of the Data ruturning as a single status line with my count it's not grouping them correctly:

```
Select  ti.Status [Status]
      , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Local_Sent With(Nolock) Where ls.localID = LO.ID and ls.STID = 7) [Delivered]
      , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Local_Sent With(Nolock) Where ls.localID = LO.ID and ls.STID = 6) [Duplicate]
      , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Local_Sent With(Nolock) Where ls.localID = LO.ID and ls.STID = 10) [Error: Invalid]
      , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Local_Sent With(Nolock) Where ls.localID = LO.ID and ls.STID = 2) [Sent]
      , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Local_Sent With(Nolock) Where ls.localID = LO.ID and ls.STID = 9) [Undelivered]
From Local LO With(Nolock)
Inner Join Local_Sent ls With(Nolock)
    On LO.ID = ls.localID
Inner Join ls.StatusID SS
    ON ls.StatusID = SS.ID
Inner Join FileStatus FS
    On M.FileStatus = FS.ID
Where Convert(varchar,ls.LoDate,23) = DateAdd(day,-1, Convert(Varchar,GETDATE(),23))
Group By ti.Status, M.ID, ls.LoDate
```

**Return Result**:

```
Status Of Matters   Delivered   Duplicate   Error:  Invalid Sent    Undelivered
Broken Files            28          5           0         0         7
Follow-up File          2           0           0         0         13
Broken Files            1           0           0         0         15
Fixed Files             50          0           0         0         0
Fixed Files             11          0           0         0         4
Broken Files            1           0           0         0         4
Attempt Files           1           0           0         1         1
Follow-up File          7           1           0         1         21
Attempting Files        2           0           0         0         0
Fixed Files             16          0           0         0         0
```

**I would like it to return:**

```
Status Of Matters   Delivered   Duplicate   Error:  Invalid Sent    Undelivered
Broken Files          50            10          0         0         20
Follow-up File        10            2           0         1         15
Fixed Files           12            0           0         0         15
Attempt Files         20            0           0         0         8
```

Comment: Your query is not readable. Please format it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
Select  ti.Status [Status]
      , SUM(CASE WHEN ls.STID = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Delivered]
      , SUM(CASE WHEN ls.STID = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Duplicate]
      , SUM(CASE WHEN ls.STID = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Error: Invalid]
      , SUM(CASE WHEN ls.STID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Sent]
      , SUM(CASE WHEN ls.STID = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Undelivered]
From Local LO With(Nolock)
Inner Join Local_Sent ls With(Nolock)
    On LO.ID = ls.localID
Inner Join ls.StatusID SS
    ON ls.StatusID = SS.ID
Inner Join FileStatus FS
    On M.FileStatus = FS.ID
Where Convert(varchar,ls.LoDate,23) = DateAdd(day,-1, Convert(Varchar,GETDATE(),23)
GROUP BY ti.Status
```